# on success display result on previous selector

Tags: jquery

I'd like to display result of my ajax call success to the previous div of my form.

--My div to update

```
<div id="data">   </div>
```

-- My ajaxbutton

```
 <div id='ajaxbutton'>
        <input type="submit" name="yt0" value="Update Data" id="yt0" />
    </div>
```

My jquery

```
jQuery('body').on('click','#yt0',function(){jQuery.ajax({'type':'POST',
                  'success':function(string){ 
                             var $thisClicked = $(this);
                             $(this).prev().html(string).slideDown(2000);
```

...

So when I click the button, nothing happens, it does not apparently find the selector.

I must add the following,

1. when I use

   ```
   $("#data").html(string).slideDown(2000);
   ```

instead of

```
     $(this).prev().html(string).slideDown(2000);
```

it works.  But I need to be dynamic.

`2.`  I cannot use the technique of inserting `data-id="1"`  within

```
<input type="submit" name="yt0" value="Update Data" id="yt0" />
```

because it is a generated button

`3.` slidedown has no effect

--  Added body section of html

```
<body>

<div class="container" id="page">

    <div id="header">
        <div id="logo">My Web Application</div>
    </div><!-- header -->

    <a href="/blog/index.php/post/16">16</a>    
    <b> Subject:</b>
        blabla A
    </br>
        <div class="formComment"> </div>
            <p><input type ="button" id="comment16" 
                value="Comment"></p>
</div>  
<div id="data">

</div>
<div id='ajaxbutton'>
<input type="submit" name="yt0" value="Update Data" id="yt0" /></div>

<a href="/blog/index.php/post/17">16</a>    
    <b> Subject:</b>
        blabla B
    </br>
        <div class="formComment"> </div>
            <p><input type ="button" id="comment18" 
                value="Comment"></p>
</div>  
<div id="data">

</div>
<div id='ajaxbutton'>
<input type="submit" name="yt1" value="Update Data" id="yt1" /></div>

</body>
```

**--  div id="data"   will become div id=data+number of id_post, that's why I need to be dynammic--**

Any help?

Comment: Can yo show us the HTML as a whole so that we can see the structure?

Comment: Probably, you have wrongs with `prev` function (your `data` element is not previous from `button`). Could you add full part of your html from div with `id="data"` to button?

Answer (score 0):

Okey, firstly, you should not have several elements on page with same `id` (such as `data`). Probably, it is better to use `class` for their.

And your element `data` is not previous from button (it is previous from parent of button). You should use following code:

```
$(this).parent().prev().html(string).slideDown(2000);
```